# Keep getting an error in PythonAnywhere while using Paste.ee api

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, pastebin

I am using the paste.ee api in my application but I keep getting the following error:

> requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.paste.ee', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/pastes (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

The code works fine on my local machine but I get the above error here. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Assuming the code works on your local machine, perhaps the server from which you  are running your application is sitting behind a proxy and require proxy configuration.  Refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287360/http-tunnel-connection-failed-403-forbidden-error-with-python-web-scraping

Comment: If you are using free account on pythonanywhere only sites from [white list](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) can be accessed. Your URL is not on the list. You will need paid account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you a free user? Free users on PythonAnywhere have restricted internet access to whitelisted domains (usually open and public APIs). If the endpoint you're trying to access is not whitelisted yet, you may request adding it by providing a link do the official documentation to the staff (on forums or via email).

Comment: The same thing happens when accessing the PDF.co API: requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.pdf.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/file/upload/get-presigned-url?contenttype=application/octet-stream&name=12_2024_01_04_11_37_53_JBU_LAB_2020.pdf (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Comment: I  don't see `api.pdf.co` on the whitelist, check [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RequestingAllowlistAdditions/) for instructions on how to request a whitelist addition.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://pastee.github.io/docs/#pastes), you'll need to supply an API key to paste.ee, otherwise you'll get a 403 error (which is what you seem to be getting).
[The documentation has a section mentioning how you get an API key.](https://pastee.github.io/docs/#authentication)

Comment: Obviously they have key if the code works on their local machine