# I am getting Proxy errors after deploying to pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I developed a web application that uses the Omdb API to import movie data into the database using `json()`. I have successfully deployed this project to PythonAnywhere, and the web app runs at first glance. However when I search a movie and then try to click on said movie to import to database and review, I get this error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='m.media-amazon.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /images/M/MV5BMTIwMzExNDEwN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwODMxMzg2._V1_SX300.jpg (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to solve this?

Also to add, when I run the application on my local machine and host, it runs successfully without any error. So I am guessing the error is from deploying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep getting an error in PythonAnywhere while using Paste.ee api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819481/keep-getting-an-error-in-pythonanywhere-while-using-paste-ee-api)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a free or paid account? I don't have enough rep to comment on the post so I'll have to ask here, if you are using a free account then this seems to be because the website is not in the [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) of sites that pythonanywhere allows and you should consider upgrading your account.

Comment: Thank you! I just upgraded and it worked. Thank you.